# How to transfer XML-nodes unchanged to output with XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I am transforming a XML document into a HTML document via XSLT. My XML document tolerates some HTML-Tags to be used within special tags:

```
<Sequence>Order pizza</Sequence>
```

or alternatively

```
<Sequence>
  <ol>
    <li>Order pizza</li>
    <li>Switch on television</li>
  </ol>
</Sequence>
```

How do I tell the transformation to transfer over the tags `<ol>`, `<li>` etc. unchanged to the output - in my case the HTML as follows:

```
<p>
  <ol>
    <li>Order pizza</li>
    <li>Switch on television</li>
  </ol>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can choose one of two possible strategies.

Either:

- pass *all* nodes to the output unchanged as the default, and add
  templates matching only the nodes you want to modify as the exception;

or:

- have a template that matches the nodes you want to pass unchanged
  explicitly.

Here's an implementation of the first strategy:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Sequence">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

In your specific example, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Sequence">
    <p>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```